# UITableView with sections prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I am working on a `UITableView` with multiple sections. Each section has a multiple of items driven from different arrays. When I click the cell from any section I want the name of the item to pass to an another view controller. I know how to use the `prepareForSegue` function with one array, but I need your help with more than one array.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let secondScene=segue.destinationViewController as! nextPageViewController

    if let indexPath=self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
        let array1=TableData[indexPath.row]

        secondScene.currentPhoto=array1
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to demonstrate using your data structures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your model is laid down like this:

```
let section1Array = ["row1", "row2"]
let section2Array = ["row1", "row2"]
let section3Array = ["row1", "row2"]

let sectionArray = [section1Array, section2Array, section3Array]
```

Here, `sectionArray` derives your sections and `section1Array`, `section2Array` & `section3Array` derives your individual section rows.

Having said that, this is how you would retrieve and send this data to your second scene:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let secondScene = segue.destinationViewController as! nextPageViewController

    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let currentPhoto = sectionArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        secondScene.currentPhoto = currentPhoto
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table has multiple sections, then in prepareForSegue use indexPath.section to find out which section was clicked on, which tells you which of your backing arrays to use. Then select the item from the array using indexPath.row and pass that to destinationViewController as the photo.